# JMeter Error is showing for distributed environment

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, distributed-computing, jmeter-plugins

I have Set up everything, running Jmeter-Server.bat file in slave system, added IP in Jmeter.properties. It was running before one month properly, but when I am trying to run, Its showing me the Error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there is a mismatch between certificates in master and slave(s) or 7 days had passed since the last keystore creation so the certificates are exired now.

Either follow steps from [Setting up SSL](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#setup_ssl) one more time and make sure to use exactly the same `rmi_keystore.jks` file on master and all the slaves or define the following property:

```
server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

This can be done either by adding the above line to *user.properties* file or alternatively you can provide it using -J command-line argument like:

- `jmeter -Jserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true .....` - on master
- `jmeter-server -Jserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true .....` - on slaves

More information:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

Comment: I have used the same rmi_keystore.jks file for both master and slave but now it's showing me the error non-JRMP server at remote end point after selecting the slave IP.